# How to select the first value within a group - without filtering?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, grouping, tidyverse

I'm trying to find a sudden decrease in a value (column `v44`) within many small groups (of `file_id` and `type`) in a dataframe/tibble (`dat`).

I want to first get rid of all the values that are too high or too low and then select the first one. I calculate the difference between values, `v44_diff`. The first value within each group should then be used for flagging subsequent values, which should not show a greater than `fac`* the decrease than the initial value.

EDIT: Ok ok, I've rewritten below to a small reprex.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

min <- 3000
max <- 50000
fac <- 1.5

dat <- tribble( ~ file_id, ~ type, ~ cycle, ~ v44,
               "hey", "std", 0, 50300,
               "hey", "std", 1, 40000,
               "hey", "std", 2, 35000,
               "hey", "std", 3, 32000,
               "hey", "std", 4, 31000,
               "hey", "std", 5, 30000,
               "hey", "std", 6, 29500,
               "hey", "smp", 1, 40100,
               "hey", "smp", 2, 35100,
               "hey", "smp", 3, 32100,
               "hey", "smp", 4, 5000,
               "hey", "smp", 5, 20,
               "hey", "smp", 6, 10,
               "hi", "std", 0, 49000,
               "hi", "std", 1, 39700,
               "hi", "std", 2, 32000,
               "hi", "std", 3, 30000,
               "hi", "std", 4, 29500,
               "hi", "std", 5, 29400,
               "hi", "std", 6, 29200,
               "hi", "smp", 1, 49100,
               "hi", "smp", 2, 39600,
               "hi", "smp", 3, 31100,
               "hi", "smp", 4, 30000,
               "hi", "smp", 5, 29600,
               "hi", "smp", 6, 29400)

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cycle, y = v44, colour = type)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = paste(file_id, type))) +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(type))
```

[image]

```r
dat %>%
    group_by(file_id, type) %>%
    mutate(v44_low = v44 <= min,  # creates a flag
           v44_high = v44 >= max,
           v44_diff = lead(v44) - v44) %>%
    mutate(v44_drop = v44_diff < fac * first(filter(., !v44_low, !v44_high)$v44_diff)) %>%
    ungroup(file_id, type)
#> # A tibble: 26 x 8
#>    file_id type  cycle   v44 v44_low v44_high v44_diff v44_drop
#>    <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   <lgl>       <dbl> <lgl>   
#>  1 hey     std       0 50300 FALSE   TRUE       -10300 TRUE    
#>  2 hey     std       1 40000 FALSE   FALSE       -5000 FALSE   
#>  3 hey     std       2 35000 FALSE   FALSE       -3000 FALSE   
#>  4 hey     std       3 32000 FALSE   FALSE       -1000 FALSE   
#>  5 hey     std       4 31000 FALSE   FALSE       -1000 FALSE   
#>  6 hey     std       5 30000 FALSE   FALSE        -500 FALSE   
#>  7 hey     std       6 29500 FALSE   FALSE          NA NA      
#>  8 hey     smp       1 40100 FALSE   FALSE       -5000 FALSE   
#>  9 hey     smp       2 35100 FALSE   FALSE       -3000 FALSE   
#> 10 hey     smp       3 32100 FALSE   FALSE      -27100 TRUE    
#> # … with 16 more rows
```

but this turned out to be very very slow, as there are many groups.

See https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3294 for an explanation of why filtering within many groups is slow.

I know how to rewrite this to a faster version, but it will still create a copy:

```
out <- dat %>%
  group_by(file_id, type) %>%
  mutate(v44_low = v44 <= min,
         v44_high = v44 >= max,
         v44_diff = lead(v44) - v44) %>%
  filter(!v44_low, !v44_high) %>%
  mutate(v44_drop = v44_diff < fac * first(.$v44_diff)) %>%
  select(file_id, type, cycle, v44_drop)

out <- dat %>%
    left_join(out, by = c("file_id", "type", "cycle")) %>%
    ungroup(file_id, type)
out
#> # A tibble: 26 x 5
#>    file_id type  cycle   v44 v44_drop
#>    <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   
#>  1 hey     std       0 50300 NA      
#>  2 hey     std       1 40000 FALSE   
#>  3 hey     std       2 35000 FALSE   
#>  4 hey     std       3 32000 FALSE   
#>  5 hey     std       4 31000 FALSE   
#>  6 hey     std       5 30000 FALSE   
#>  7 hey     std       6 29500 NA      
#>  8 hey     smp       1 40100 FALSE   
#>  9 hey     smp       2 35100 FALSE   
#> 10 hey     smp       3 32100 TRUE    
#> # … with 16 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is because I want to keep the rows with high/low values, but I don't want them to be used to calculate the difference.

Is there any way I can rewrite this to be faster? Where I don't have to filter within groups, and I don't have to create a copy to merge back into the final result?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example so someone can help test your code and suggest a new result.

Comment: Ok I did. I thought I could get the idea across with pseudocode, but I already feared it would be too vague :(. Hope with the reprex it's understandable now!

Comment: I suspect there might be an error in OP's code, IIUC. `.` refers to the entire data frame, not to each group. Try replacing `fac * first(filter(., ` with `fac * print(first(filter(.,` to see what I mean. It prints `5000` four times, while I reckon you'd expect it to print `-5000`, `-5000`, `-9300`, `-9500`

Comment: Do you mean `mutate(v44_drop = v44_diff < fac * v44_diff[!v44_low & !v44_high][1])` ?

Comment: @Aurèle yes, the latter! But I tried to do it within groups, so I thought using `filter` would work. My second solution definitely works, but there I first have to create a copy and then left_join it back in.

Comment: "definitely works"? Are you sure? It seems the issue with `.` referring to the entire data frame is still present. What about replacing the `mutate` line in your first attempt with mine then? Should solve the issue I pointed out, and eliminate the need for `filter` at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do group_by, `first` operates on a group level. So for example we use a simple test:

```
dat %>%
group_by(file_id, type) %>%
mutate(is_first = v44 == first(v44))

# A tibble: 26 x 5
# Groups:   file_id, type [4]
   file_id type  cycle   v44 is_first
   <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   
 1 hey     std       0 50300 TRUE    
 2 hey     std       1 40000 FALSE   
 3 hey     std       2 35000 FALSE   
 4 hey     std       3 32000 FALSE   
 5 hey     std       4 31000 FALSE   
 6 hey     std       5 30000 FALSE   
 7 hey     std       6 29500 FALSE   
 8 hey     smp       1 40100 TRUE    
 9 hey     smp       2 35100 FALSE   
10 hey     smp       3 32100 FALSE
```

But if you call .$v44, you are doing it for the whole data.frame, outside of the group:

```
dat %>%
group_by(file_id, type) %>%
mutate(is_first = v44 == first(.$v44))

   file_id type  cycle   v44 is_first
   <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   
 1 hey     std       0 50300 TRUE    
 2 hey     std       1 40000 FALSE   
 3 hey     std       2 35000 FALSE   
 4 hey     std       3 32000 FALSE   
 5 hey     std       4 31000 FALSE   
 6 hey     std       5 30000 FALSE   
 7 hey     std       6 29500 FALSE   
 8 hey     smp       1 40100 FALSE   
 9 hey     smp       2 35100 FALSE   
10 hey     smp       3 32100 FALSE
```

You can see for row 8, the first value doesn't show TRUE. So if you are only defining differences within the group, do not use .$ .

From the problem you have described, you only need to work on the vector. If you use filter, you are working on the whole data frame, so my suggestion is to use [ which works on the vector. In the example below I also replaced the differences for values outside min and max with 0:

```
test = dat %>%
  group_by(file_id, type) %>%
  mutate(v44_diff = lead(v44) - v44) %>%
  mutate(v44_diff = replace(v44_diff,v44 < min | v44 > max,0)) %>%
  mutate(v44_drop = v44_diff < fac*first(v44_diff[v44_diff!=0])) %>%
  ungroup(file_id, type)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Question though: is filtering within groups with `[` not as problematic as with `filter` is? i.e. would this issue https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3294 not occur when using base within groups?

Comment: when you use filter, you are working on the whole data frame, as opposed to [ which works on the vector. You only need to work on the vector, and you want to keep the data.frame.

Comment: Nice, if you tweak your answer to include that I'll mark it as accepted!
I ended up not using the `replace` part, as that gets rid of the "real" differences, and I need the two `v44_high` and `v44_low` columns anyway later on in the process. But simply switching to base `[` ended up fixing the problem :).

Comment: Also, thanks for the claryfication on `.$`. That was a sloppy leftover from my `.data$` pronoun since this  stuff is part of a package.

Comment: Cool. glad you can take some parts of it. I wasn't very sure about some parts of your question, just trying my best.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following generic steps:-

### Suppose the name of the variable in which you are storing the data is my_data

create a new variable excluding the head and tail of the original dataset

my_new_data <- as.data.frame(my_data, c(my_data != head(my_data)| my_data != tail(my_data)))

Try this...

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make myself clear. I don't want to get rid of the first and last rows in the data, I want to: 1 group the data, 2 filter out extreme values 3 select the first one and 4 check if any of the remaining ones have a diff larger than this.

Comment: This steps will not affect your original data frame. You can use this steps to just select a specific data ranges and experiment with them.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I wrote a wrong command, Instead of  my_new_data <- as.data.frame(my_data, c(my_data != head(my_data)| my_data != tail(my_data)), write this my_new_data <- subset(my_data, c(my_data != head(my_data)| my_data != tail(my_data))